# Set $E_{pq}=\{x\in E: f(x)>p>q>g(x)\}$ is of zero measure for any $p$ and $q$, prove $f(x)\leq g(x) a.e.$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Problem:

> Functions $f$ and $g$ are Lebesgue measurable on $E\subset\mathbb{R}$. Set $E_{pq}=\{x\in E: f(x)>p>q>g(x)\}$ is of zero measure for any $p$ and $q$, prove $f(x)\leq g(x)\ a.e.$

My proof: Assume $F=\{x\in E:f(x)>g(x)\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}=\{p_1,p_2,...,p_n,...\}$. Then $$F=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\{x\in E:f(x)>p_n>g(x)\}=\cup_{n=1}^\infty(\{x\in E:f(x)>p_n\}\cap\{x\in E:p_n>g(x)\})$$ Assume $\{q_{nj}\}_{j=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{q_{nj}\}$ increasingly converges to $p_n$. Then $$F=\cup_{n=1}^\infty(\{x\in E:f(x)>p_n\}\cap\cup_{j=1}^\infty\{x\in E:g(x)<q_{nj}\})\\=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{j=1}^\infty(\{x\in E:f(x)>p_n\}\cap\{x\in E:g(x)<q_{nj}\})\\=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{j=1}^\infty E_{p_n q_{nj}}$$ So $m(F)=0$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks!

Comment: But it is easier to write $$F = \bigcup_{(p,q) \in \mathbb Q^2, p>q } E_{p,q}.$$

Comment: @Smith: Indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Nicely done. Correct.